# Having Jenkins show Subversion changes with hyperlinks that show differences

Tags: svn, jenkins

For the build e-mail that goes out, I am using "${CHANGES}" to get a list of SVN changes since the last successful build.  I would like that to include hyperlinks to actual (visual) diffs for the individual checkins.  I googled around and saw some plugins that do diffs, but it seems like they were just doing what "${CHANGES}" provided, and not really what I'm looking for...

Comment: But what place are you going to hyperlink? Are you using some web visualizing tool? Gerrit or something similar?

Comment: Interposed question: Where did you get the information about `${CHANGES}?` Neither [Jenkins Set Environment Variables](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-JenkinsSetEnvironmentVariables) nor [Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) mention it.

Comment: Yeah, some web visualizing tool or something.  Just seems like it would be so convenient.

Comment: Not quite sure where ${CHANGES} came from (I inherited this jenkins system).  I just googled it and it looks like it's from an "All Changes" plugin?? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/All+Changes+Plugin

Comment: Googling around, it looks like VisualSVN or Trac might be able to do this??

Answer (score 1):

See <your project's config> → *Source Code Management* → *Subversion* → *Repository browser* → [image]:

> *Adds links in "changes" views within Jenkins to an external system for browsing the details of those changes. The "Auto" selection attempts to infer the repository browser from other jobs, if supported by the SCM and a job with matching SCM details can be found.*

The drop-down list of browsers here (Jenkins v1.609.1, Subversion Plug-in v2.5.1) contains:

- Assembla
- CollabNet
- FishEye
- SVN::Web
- Sventon 1.x/2.x
- ViewSVN
- WebSVN

Answer (score 0):

This will likely depend on what software you're using for viewing repository changesets.

If you're using Trac, then Jenkins' [Trac Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Trac+Plugin) should be able to do what you're looking for.  There are also plugins for systems like [WebSVN](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebSVN2+Plugin) and [ViewVC](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ViewVC+Plugin).